# Regex re.sub on file font matter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Im trying to retrieve the front matter form a `.md` file, I could able to retrieve the content when every head of my front matter is in one line.

Ex:

```
---
title: "Meeting"
date: 2019-03-14T07:51:28+01:00
draft: false
status:["process", "todo"]
---
```

So I wrote the following python script to get the front matter content

```
def get_front_matter(file, start='---', end='---'):
    """Strip file and retrieve front matter then format the value"""
    content = {}
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file_content:
        for content_line in file_content:
            if content_line.strip() == start:
                break
        for content_line in file_content:
            if content_line.strip() == end:
                break

            line_data = content_line.split(':', 1)
            # If we cannot split decently, carry on
            if len(line_data) != 2:
                continue
            # format the string to store in dict for better usage
            content[line_data[0]] = re.sub(r"[\n\t]*", "", line_data[1]).strip(' "')
    return content
```

But I face an issue if my front mater `status` has in multiple lines.

```
---
title: "Meeting"
date: 2019-03-14T07:51:28+01:00
draft: false
status:
  [
    "process",
    "todo",
    "hold"
  ]
---
```

When i try to read the above file front matter i get a blank value to `status` but it should be as follows:

```
{'title': 'Meeting', 'date': '2019-03-14T07:51:28+01:00', 'draft': 'false', 'teams': '["process", "todo", "hold"]'}
```

Is there any other way to read the content of the front matter based on the lines or tags. I tried with a few regex but I can't retrieve a set of lines.

Comment: Front matter usually comes in a common format, and your header looks suspiciously like YAML. Are you sure you need to parse it manually?

Comment: I dont have any option to do it as the md files are generated already i cant change them now :(

Comment: I'm asking whether the header *is* YAML, not whether you can change it to it.

Comment: Yes it is. im also trying with other solutions now https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/how-to-parse-frontmatter-with-python/

Comment: If it's yaml you can just split out the bits between the dashlines and feed it to pyyaml.

Comment: No, It increases the complexity by reading other contents of the file. So i cant use the python pyyaml, i think i need to manually read the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept almost your code, the key was **to not add the value to result before we
make sure that we collected the full`value` (when it's split in multiple lines)** , this is done by verifying the next `str` line, if it's a valid value `(key: some value)` then add the previous `key` with its `content` to result or if it's the end character `---`, I hope comments make thing more clearer

```py
    def get_front_matter(file, start='---', end='---'):
        """Strip file and retrieve front matter then format the value"""
        result = {}
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file_content:
            for content_line in file_content:
                if content_line.strip() == start:
                    break

            content = ''
            key = ''
            for content_line in file_content:
                if content_line.strip() == end:
                    if key and content:
                        # add last key: content before breaking out
                        result[key] = re.sub(r"[\n\t]*", "", content).strip (' "')
                    break

                line_data = content_line.split(':', 1)
                if len(line_data) == 2 and not content:
                    # this is our first key: content, in this point we don't have previous content so we should keep them and check the next value first
                    key = line_data[0]
                    content = line_data[1]
                    continue
                elif len(line_data) == 2:  # we found another valid value 
                    # add previous (key, content) and keep the new (key , content)
                    result[key] = re.sub(r"[\n\t]*", "", content).strip(' "')
                    key = line_data[0]
                    content = line_data[1]
                else:
                    # not a valid key: value add it to previous value because it's a value splited in multiple line
                    content += content_line

        return result
```

**Note**: I changed content name with result, and this code will break for case like this:

```
     title: "Meeting"
    date: 2019-03-14T07:51:28+01:00
    draft: false
    status:
      [
        "somevalue:process",  # if the value contains ':'
        "todo",
        "hold"
      ]
```

Here you didn't specify how we distinct between key, and value that contains ':' if it is not preceded by its key. I hope this will not make 
a problem for you

Comment: Fantastic @CharifDZ. Thank you. It took a bit for me to understand the logic but yeah its perfect. Thanks a ton.! hope this helps others too..